# Instead of submiting an entire post, is there any way to submit a lite-post or a simple message?

Tags: posts, database

I was wondering if there is a way or a plugin to post something like twitter update messages instead of a post.

Something like http://p2demo.wordpress.com/ but better, where a user will post update messages not an entire post (in database matters). That means you will save space, make it quicker and fewer database resources.

I am looking for a way to post lite messages, that database will only save the must, like IDs, title, post and a thumb, through php maybe. No taxonomies and and and.

I hope you understand what I am trying to say (sorry for any bad English)

Thank you.

**Updated**:  I found this code, should I use this as a twitter posting feature? (As I said I need fewer db resources)

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title']    = 'My post';
$my_post['post_content']  = 'This is my post.';
$my_post['post_status']   = 'publish';
$my_post['post_author']   = 1;
$my_post['post_category'] = array(0);
// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );"
```

Comment: I think you're striving for optimisation in the wrong place. You'd get a much better reward implementing a front-end cache like [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) or [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) if you're after speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted is about the same one WordPress uses to insert posts in to the database so it's not really saving anything.

But i would suggest you use [Custom Post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and only allow a few or as much as needed objects to it :

- 'title'
- 'author'
- 'excerpt'
- 'custom-fields'
- 'comments' (assuming you want to allow comments.)

This will not save you any extra unneeded fields (not more the the minimum needed by WordPress).

And if that is still not good enough the your best bet would be to create your own database table and only store what you need in it.

Comment: I would go one better and also use the `status` [post format](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) :)

Comment: and this can be done with raw php code only? I guess p2 should have considered of making something lite for update messages

Comment: Yes this can be done in raw php but why? This is really the wrong place to look for optimization. Like thedeadmedic said, you'll get better results using some frontend cache mechanism.